# Pick up first and last result with Json and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

How to get only 2 items from an Api. In the case the first and last.
I want to get the first and last thing like this:
01 ~ 05

```html
"capitulos":{  
            "dados":[  
               {  
                  "id":"169461",
                  "capitulo":"01"
               },

               {
                  "id":"16942",
                  "capitulo":"02"
               },
      
               {
                  "id":"169463",
                  "capitulo":"03"
               },

               {
                  "id":"169464",
                  "capitulo":"04"
               },
     
               {
                  "id":"169465",
                  "capitulo":"05"
               },
              ] 
             },
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want the json service to only return those 2 items? That has to be supported by that api.

Comment: I want to get only the first result and the last, in this case, chapter 1 and 5.

Comment: just read first and last item from your response list

Comment: Is there something you have already tried?

Comment: I tried this: 
ultimosLancados ultimosLancados = response.body (). get (1); final ArrayList <Lancamentos> listaLancamentos = ultimosLancados.getDados ();

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `JSON` String to Object using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) and then take the first and last element as below:

```
static void printFirstAndLastCapitulo(Capitulos obj) {
      System.out.println("Capitulo of first result is " + obj.dados[0].capitulo); 
      System.out.println("Capitulo of last result is " + obj.dados[obj.dados.length-1].capitulo); 
    }
```

Again this is just to give you an idea, but all validations of size etc. needs to be taken care.

**Complete code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "{\"dados\":[{\"id\":\"169461\",\"capitulo\":\"01\"},{\"id\":\"16942\",\"capitulo\":\"02\"},{\"id\":\"169463\",\"capitulo\":\"03\"},{\"id\":\"169464\",\"capitulo\":\"04\"},{\"id\":\"169465\",\"capitulo\":\"05\"}]}";

        Capitulos jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(data, Capitulos.class);
        printFirstAndLastCapitulo(jsonObject);
    }

    static void printFirstAndLastCapitulo(Capitulos obj) {
        System.out.println("Capitulo of first result is " + obj.dados[0].capitulo);
        System.out.println("Capitulo of last result is " + obj.dados[obj.dados.length - 1].capitulo);
    }

    static class JsonClass {
        private Capitulos capitulos;

        public Capitulos getCapitulos() {
            return capitulos;
        }

        public void setCapitulos(Capitulos capitulos) {
            this.capitulos = capitulos;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ClassPojo [capitulos = " + capitulos + "]";
        }
    }

    static class Capitulos {
        private Dados[] dados;

        public Dados[] getDados() {
            return dados;
        }

        public void setDados(Dados[] dados) {
            this.dados = dados;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ClassPojo [dados = " + dados + "]";
        }
    }

    static class Dados {
        private String id;

        private String capitulo;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getCapitulo() {
            return capitulo;
        }

        public void setCapitulo(String capitulo) {
            this.capitulo = capitulo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ClassPojo [id = " + id + ", capitulo = " + capitulo + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that I can help you further with your code as I cant see any terminology mentioned in your question in the code shared. Hope above will help you to fix it.